# SQLAlchemy - what is declarative_base

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning `sqlalchemy`.
Here is my initial code :

**user.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Sequence, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'users'
   id = Column(Integer,Sequence('user_seq'), primary_key=True)
   username = Column(String(50), unique=True)
   fullname = Column(String(150))
   password = Column(String(50))
   def __init__(self, name, fullname, password):
      self.name = name
      self.fullname = fullname
      self.password = password
```

**main.py**

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from user import User
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   engine = create_engine('mysql://root:password@127.0.0.1:3306/test', echo=True)
   Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
   Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
   session = Session()
   ed_user = User('ed', 'Ed Jones', 'edspassword')
   session.add(ed_user)
   session.commit()
```

When I run **main.py**, it won't create tables automatically and gives me an exception on `session.commit()`.

Also, when I move line `Base = declarative_base()` to any different module and use the same `Base` variable in **main.py** and in **user.py** - it creates the table.

My question: "What is `declarative_base`" ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[`declarative_base()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html) is a factory function that constructs a base class for declarative class definitions (which is assigned to the `Base` variable in your example). The one you created in user.py is associated with the `User` model, while the other one (in main.py) is a different class and doesn't know anything about your models, that's why the `Base.metadata.create_all()` call didn't create the table. You need to import `Base` from user.py

```py
from user import User, Base
```

instead of creating a new `Base` class in main.py.

Comment: I created new file & put following two lines <br/>                      line 1 :  from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
line 2 :  Base = declarative_base()
<br/>I created that way because I am creating multiple model classes in different files. No specific reason behind that, It just I used create beans in that way in java. Thanks for answer.

Comment: @Aniruddha Thanks for the tip. I also put those 2 lines in the module's `__init__.py` file & `from mymodule import Base`

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/declarative/basic_use.html seems to be deprecated

Comment: @Aniruddha I think that approach is wrong. In FastAPI we have similar situation. Can you please provide some update on this. How will this line `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` behave in your approach.

Comment: @DheemanthBhat please add your answer / comments explaining your approach.  I bit disconnected from python for some times now.  Will try to check these things during weekend.