# How to do database migration when i create models using Sqlcodegen

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

Here is the models, where if any changes happen in the code future it will automatically reflect into the database,

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import  Column, Integer, String, Table, Text, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey


engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:root@localhost:5432/12june')
Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)
session=Session(engine)

class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Company'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'public'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    servername = Column(String(255))
    companyname = Column(String(250))


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': 'public'}

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    fname = Column(String(100))
    lname = Column(String(100))
    dp = Column(String(260))
    email = Column(String(260))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with app.app_context():
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=3000, debug=True)
```

i have more than 300+ models table, i tried many ways but could not succesed yet

i can do this if i create models like below
but my models is little bit diffrent,

does anybody has solution/suggestions for this...!

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15176114/8230309) from models import User, Base